# OpenMP - Binary tree

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm trying to run a simple program to run in parallel. I want to base it on a binary tree. Based on the number of processors I want to distribute work to all of them, so that program runs in parallel. Using recursion, I'm checking if there are 1 or 2 processors left, and if so I'm using OpenMP `sections` to run it. However, the more cores it uses, the slower the algorithm, and I don't understand why. I tried to write code as self-explanatory as I could.

```
void fun1(int tab[], int pocz, int kon, int threadsLeft)
{
    if (threadsLeft == 2)
    {
        #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
        {
            #pragma omp sections nowait
            {
                #pragma omp section
                {
                    for (int i = pocz; i < kon/2; i++)
                    {
                        tab[i] = 1;
                    }

                }
                #pragma omp section
                {
                    for(int i = kon/2 + 1; i < kon; i++)
                    {
                        tab[i] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (threadsLeft == 1)
    {
        #pragma omp parallel num_threads(1)
        {
            #pragma omp sections nowait
            {
                #pragma omp section
                {
                    for (int i = pocz; i < kon; i++)
                    {
                        tab[i] = 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fun1(tab, pocz, kon/2, threadsLeft/2);
        fun1(tab, kon - kon/2, kon, threadsLeft - threadsLeft / 2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int allThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    int N = 200000000;
    int* tab = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        tab[i] = 0;
    }
    fun1(tab, 0, N, allThreads);
}
```

Comment: Your question title is not helpful for understanding the problem; please review [ask] and then [edit] it to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, you have two issues.

The first problem is that in your main function, outside of a parallel region, `omp_get_num_threads()` should always return 1. So call this inside a parallel region in order to access how many threads of your current parallel region you have.

The second problem is that you have a recursive problem, which lends itself towards task parallelism. OpenMP `sections` are best used with a constant *a-priori* known number of sections. OpenMP `tasks` are designed to handle recursive problems where the number of *tasks* you want to spawn is not necessarily known. For instance, check out this [basic tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenMP/Tasks). Note, your compiler must support OpenMP 3.0 for this to work.

Putting both of those together, your new `#pragma omp tasks` code should look something like as follows:

```
void fun1(int tab[], int pocz, int kon, int threadsLeft)
{
    if (threadsLeft <= 1) {
        for (int i = pocz; i < kon; i++)
            tab[i] = 2; // should make this constant something else to be more helpful
    }
    else
    {
        #pragma omp task
        fun1(tab, pocz, kon/2, threadsLeft/2);
        #pragma omp task
        fun1(tab, kon - kon/2, kon, threadsLeft - threadsLeft/2);
        #pragma omp taskwait
    }
}

int main()
{

    int N = 200000000;
    int* tab = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        tab[i] = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel
    // Only the first thread will spawn other threads
    #pragma omp single nowait
    {
        int allThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        fun1(tab, 0, N, allThreads);
    }

}
```

Fair warning: I have not tested this code myself, so take it with a grain of salt.